# Android/Java: onProgressUpdate() not being called?

Tags: java, android, breakpoints

I've read similar threads on here, even googled but no solution.

onProgressUpdate() is just not being called.

Here's the code:

```
public class DoHardWork extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {


        publishProgress("Requesting XML data");
        this.requestData();

        publishProgress("Returning results");
        this.returnResults();

        return null;
    }



    protected void onProgressUpdate(String text) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(text);
        MainActivity.setLog(text);
    }
}
```

I tried setting a breakpoint in onProgressUpdate() and it's never called. It's like the code is just ignored.

Someone had a similar problem and it turned out to be just eclipse just messing with him but i tried restarting it with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that you missed somethings on your code. Try with this one:

```
private class DoHardWork extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... urls) {
         publishProgress("Requesting XML data");
         this.requestData();

         publishProgress("Returning results");
         this.returnResults();

         return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        MainActivity.setLog(progress[0]);
    }


}
```

Comment: That did it! I'm kind of new to Java so i tried to keep it as simple as possible, i didn't know generics was required. One more question though, why can't i call publishProgress() from onCancelled()? That seems like it should be possible.

Comment: You could call publishProgress() but on the second value of the generic you have to put Void, Like this: DoHardWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long>. Take a look to this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Even better, add @Override on your method declaration, you won't have to guess whether you did it right, compiler will do it for you.